# I want to save click image in my own folder

Tags: ionic-framework

how to save image in custom folder using ionic framework

after i take the image from my camera i want to save it in my own created folder say clickImage folder

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that, I think you need to copy the file to your local storage. For that you need to use file plugin for copyFile.
Please check below code. I hope that will work for you.

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    //you app code goes here  
  });
})
.controller('FileController', function($scope, $cordovaCamera, $cordovaFile) {
  $scope.fileName = "";
  $scope.uploadPicture = function() {
    var options = {
      quality: 50,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      allowEdit: true,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      targetWidth: 1024,
      targetHeight: 768,
      popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
      correctOrientation: true
    };

    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(sourcePath) {
      var sourceDirectory = sourcePath.substring(0, sourcePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      var sourceFileName = sourcePath.substring(sourcePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, sourcePath.length);

      console.log("Copying from : " + sourceDirectory + sourceFileName);
      console.log("Copying to : " + cordova.file.dataDirectory + sourceFileName);
      $cordovaFile.copyFile(sourceDirectory, sourceFileName, cordova.file.dataDirectory, sourceFileName).then(function(success) {
         $scope.fileName = cordova.file.dataDirectory + sourceFileName;
      }, function(error) {
         console.dir(error);
      });

    }, function(err) {
         console.log(err);
    });
  }
});
```

Thanks..

Comment: hi hiro , i tried the code which you sent but it is not working .

Comment: hi hiro bt after copy it how can i fetch the images from that data directory folder which i am easily able to do by using local storage